# .NET 4.0 and Encoding.RegisterProvider method

Tags: c#, character-encoding, thermal-printer

I write this code

```
 byte[] arr2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1001).GetBytes(st);
```

for encoding Arabic words ("رقم الفاتورة") but it throws the exception

> "No data is available for encoding 1001. For information on defining
> a custom encoding, see the documentation for the
> Encoding.RegisterProvider method."

I am using .NET 4.0.10.0 but I can't find the method `Encoding.RegisterProvider()`. I need this codepage because of my thermal printer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [list of encodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) there is no 1001.

You need to not just know the language, but the actual text encoding used. There is more than one for Arabic.

Are you using 1001 because it is the Win32 LCID for ar-ly locale? That is wrong: 1. encoding ids have nothing to do with locale ids (both are deprecated in favour of names because there are too many variants of both to be usefully mnemonic); and 2. ar-ly isn't 1001, it is 0x0101 which is 256.)

PS. `Encoding.RegisterProvider` is certainly [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.registerprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2) (and has existed since .NET 4.6 – remember the runtime version of the CLR isn't the framework version.)

Comment: If you are introduced to the encoding page, wouldn't it be more specific and appropriate to advise you to specify one of 708, 720, 864, or 1256 for arabic? However, there is no 708 for thermal printers, but either 720, 864, or 1256. [ESC t](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/ref_escpos_en/esc_lt.html) By the way, according to the document distributed on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/70feba9f-294e-491e-b6eb-56532684c37f), `ar-LY` is not 0x0101 but 0x1001, which is 4097 in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `System.Text.Encoding.CodePages` nuget package and register the encoding provider before your code, that will resolve the issue.

```
System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
// your code
byte[] arr2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1001).GetBytes(st);
```

Also you can get the right encoding from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=netframework-4.0)

Comment: thank you for responses but my thermal printer support Arabic codepage(1001_ and code page 864 when i used 864 codepage it print question mark like (??????) so i try using 1001 but fail till now i switch my project to dot net 4.6 but i can't find System.Text.Encoding.codepage refrence